# Create the mean for all possible combinations of 5 different variables

Tags: r

I have a data set with 5 different variables (e.g., a, b, c, d, and e). I want to have simple code (preferably with the tidyverse) that allows me to take the mean for each possible combination of the variables. For example, the mean of "ab", "ac", ..., all the way to "abcde". Is there a simple way of doing this?

All I've tried is manually creating the code for each variable. However, it seems like something like a loop would be more appropriate.

For example, if my data looked like this:

```
a <- rnorm(10, 0, 1)
b <- rnorm(10, 0, 1)
c <- rnorm(10, 0, 1)
d <- rnorm(10, 0, 1)
e <- rnorm(10, 0, 1)
data <- cbind.data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)
```

I want the data to look like the output as if I had done this for each combination of a, b, c, d, e:

```
data$ab <- (data$a + data$b)/2
.
.
.
data$abcde <- (data$a + data$b + data$c + data$d + data$e)/5
```

Comment: What's your dataset look like? Can you provide some sample data? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I have added an example of what the data would look like

Comment: What do you want the *output* to look like? A column of column names with a column of the mean products? In any order?

Comment: I have added a description for what I'd like the output to look like

Comment: You can use `combn` to get the column indexes in each product, but you'll have to loop over the combination sizes from 2 to 5. Does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate the combinations with `combn` and compute means for each combination with `rowMeans`:

```
all.combs <- unlist(lapply(2:ncol(data), function(x) combn(colnames(data), x, simplify = F)), recursive = F)

m <- lapply(all.combs, function(x) rowMeans(data[, x]))
data[sapply(all.combs, paste0, collapse = '')] <- m


# example output
data[, c('ab', 'ac', 'abcde')]
#            ab          ac       abcde
# 1   0.9145668 -0.15422891  0.46534449
# 2   1.0593771  0.36834739 -0.28974715
# 3   0.8504790  0.37486041  0.58032864
# 4   0.8392725  1.67687954  0.62420232
# 5  -0.1612623 -0.31145576  0.06580884
# 6  -0.6140748 -0.05931374 -0.01082605
# 7   0.4424551  0.75504165  0.53706206
# 8  -0.1202238 -0.02772524  0.43865296
# 9  -1.3020701 -0.18290837 -0.61781512
# 10 -0.7414824 -1.56409902 -1.12516693
```

Comment: This definitely gets the job done. If I can figure out a solution using the tidyverse, I'll post it.

Comment: @user2917781 something like: `map(1:ncol(df), ~ combn(colnames(df), ., simplify = FALSE)) %>%
  flatten()` should get you going in the right direction.